# Bash script to upload file by FTP

Tags: bash, ftp

I'm trying this script to create and upload files to an ftp server. The script is based in some other script seen here in the forum.

```
    HOST=example.com #This is the FTP servers host or IP address.
    USER=ftpuser #This is the FTP user that has access to the server.
    PASS=1234 #This is the password for the FTP user.
    FILE_PREFIX=FRAME

    timestamp() {
      date +"%s"
    }

    ftp() {
        ftp -i -n $HOST << END_SCRIPT
        user $USER $PASS
        # #cd /path/to/file
        put $FILENAME
        bye

    END_SCRIPT
    }

    # # Call 1. Uses the ftp command with the -inv switches. 
    # #-i turns off interactive prompting. 
    # #-n Restrains FTP from attempting the auto-login feature. 
    # #-v enables verbose and progress. 


    # shoot picture

    while true; do
        FILENAME=${FILE_PREFIX}_$(timestamp).txt
        echo $FILENAME > $FILENAME

        echo "Subiendo $FILENAME"
        ftp

        sleep 2
    done
    EOF
```

When I execute the script I get this error message:

> script.sh: 14: script.sh: 0: Too many open files

Can you help me solve the error?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename your function `ftp` to something else and its call before line with `sleep 2`.

Comment: Thanks, that worked (I have to wait 3 minutes to accept response). Now I have a new *issue*, maybe I must begin a new question but willt try here: once the ftp connection is opened I get this message in screen: *?Invalid command*

Comment: Please start a new question. It could be useful to switch to [Super User](http://superuser.com/tour).